# Converting time so it can used in a Integer

Tags: vb.net, timespan

I'm working on some code in VB that can get the average time from the speed of button press. I've got the maths done however I'm having a problem converting a TimeSpan declaration into a Integer where it can be divided and made into a average. Can you please help. Thanks!

Maths for code:

**2nd click**

```
click count = 2 
average= current time / 1
so current = time \ click count - 1
```

**3rd click**

```
adveragetime + Current Time \ clickcount - 1
```

**4th click**

```
average time * (click count -2) + Current Time \ clickcount -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the TimeSpan's `.TotalSeconds` property.